# Pandas - map column from dict values in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a simple DataFrame and a dictionary like:

```
import pandas as pd

dict = {'x' : ['a', 'c'], 'y': ['b', 'd']}
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3:'d'}})

  col1
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d
```

Now I want to do "reverse-mapping" on the dictionary to have another 'col2', and the DataFrame like this:

```
  col1 col2
0    a    x
1    b    y
2    c    x
3    d    y
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: So create a reversed mapping and use that?

Comment: while reversing the dict k:v to v:k I get "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

Comment: well yes, you have to put the individual items in the lists as keys in the dictionary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve it by using [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.0/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#dictionaries) and [`pandas.Series.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) method. The code is following.

```
>>> df['col2'] = df.col1.map({item: k for k, v in dict.items() for item in v})
>>> print(df)

  col1 col2
0    a    x
1    b    y
2    c    x
3    d    y
```