# Adding a column with user ID based on a column that has bank account id and a dictionary mapping ever user to their bank account ids

Tags: python, pandas

so I have a python dictionary of the form

where keys are user ids and values are arrays of bank account ids .
and I have a dataframe with a column bank account id

```
D = {"82":[0,2,12,15,25], "83":[56], "84":[30,31]} 
data = {'bank_account_id': [0, 2,15,12,25,30,31,56], 'amount': [3, 4,4,4,6,8,4,6,2]}
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=data)



    bank_account_id     amount
0   0   3
1   2   4
2   15  4
3   12  4
4   25  6
5   30  8
6   31  4
7   56  6


I need 

    bank_account_id     amount  user_id
0   0   3   82
1   2   4   82
2   15  4   82
3   12  4   82
4   25  6   82
5   30  8   84
6   31  4   84
7   56  6   83
```

how do i make a column user_id with 82 , 83 , 84 in their respective rows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - map column from dict values in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61135954/pandas-map-column-from-dict-values-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

Use nested list comprehension with flatten values:

```
d = {x: k for k, v in D.items() for x in v}
dataframe['user_id'] = dataframe['bank_account_id'].map(d)
print (dataframe)
   bank_account_id  amount user_id
0                0       3      82
1                2       4      82
2               15       4      82
3               12       4      82
4               25       6      82
5               30       8      84
6               31       4      84
7               56       6      83
```